# Integral of $1/x^2$ without power rule

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics

I was wondering if it was possible to evaluate the following integral without using the power rule for negative exponents

\begin{equation*}
  \int \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx
\end{equation*}

When using integration by parts, you end up with the same integral in the rhs so it seems out of luck

\begin{equation*}
  \int \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx = \frac{\ln x}{x} + \int \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \; dx
\end{equation*}

This question is inspired by this blackpenredpen's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjK8gff5vtQ)

---

Using integration by parts with $u = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $v = x$ is NOT accepted. If you write

\begin{equation*}
  \int \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx = \frac{1}{x} + 2 \int \frac{1}{x^2} \; dx
\end{equation*}

you are still implicitly using the power rule to compute the derivative of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ so it is not correct per the rules.

The same rules apply for $u$-substitution which implicitly use the power rule. See the following with $u = \frac{1}{x}$ such that

\begin{equation*}
    \int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)' \; dx = \int \frac{1}{u^2} \; du
\end{equation*}

and here the power rule is also considered used to compute the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ although it can be subject to discussion (geometric proof, limit definition of derivative, etc...)

Comment: Whatever you do, the antiderivative is $c-\dfrac1x$, so why looking for trouble ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's not looking for trouble it's a challenge inspired by a youtuber

Comment: You can use a Schwinger parameterization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another way is to substitute $x=e^t \implies dx = e^t dt $:

$$\int \frac{1}{e^{2t}} e^t dt = \int e^{-t} dt = -e^{-t} + C = -\frac 1x +C$$

Here, only the fact that $e^x$ is its own derivative is used.

Comment: I really like this one: +1

Comment: The great thing too is that it is quite easy to extend this answer to prove the power rule. For $n\neq-1$, we have $\int x^ndx$. Let $x=e^t$ and $dx=e^tdt$, then the integral becomes $\int e^{t(n+1)}dt$. Let $u=(n+1)t$, $dt=\frac{du}{n+1}$, then we have $\int \frac{e^u}{n+1}du=\frac{e^u}{n+1}=\frac{e^{(n+1)t}}{n+1}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 10):

**Updated:**

I found a new second substitute much faster:

**Method $-1$**

Let $x=\tan t$, then we have

$$\int \dfrac {1}{x^2} dx=\int \dfrac{1}{\sin ^2(t)} dt=-\cot (t)+C=-\cot (\arctan x)+C=-\dfrac 1 x+C$$

---

**Method $-2$**

How about this substitution?

Let $x=\dfrac {1}{\ln t}$, then we have
$$\int \dfrac {1}{x^2} dx=-\int \dfrac{1}{t} dt=-\ln t+C=-\dfrac 1x+C.$$

Comment: Very nice and NO power rule: +1

Comment: Using the fact that both $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}^*$ and it becomes so simple, I think it is very cool

Comment: @coshsinh I edited my answer.

Comment: If you write $\int \frac{1}{(1/x)^2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)' \; dx = \int \frac{1}{u^2} \; du$ then you still need to compute the derivative for $\frac{1}{x}$ using the power rule

Comment: @coshsinh yes you are right.  I rolled back my edits.

Comment: Initially for me your first answer was fine though. I added an edit with your case in my question, and I stated that it can be subject to discussion because plenty of proofs exist for the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ without involving the power rule

Comment: @coshsinh see my new answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Let $x=\cos \theta +i\sin \theta$. By De Moivre's Theorem, $$\frac{1}{x^2}=x^{-2}=\cos (-2\theta)+i\sin (-2\theta)=\cos (2\theta)-i\sin(2\theta)$$
Also $$dx=(-\sin \theta+i\cos \theta) d\theta$$
The integral becomes $$\int( \cos 2\theta-i\sin 2\theta)(-\sin \theta+i\cos\theta)d\theta\\
=\int (-\sin \theta\cos 2\theta+i\cos \theta\cos 2\theta+i\sin\theta\sin 2\theta+\cos \theta\sin2\theta)d\theta\\
=\int -\frac{1}{2}(\sin 3\theta-\sin \theta)+i\frac{1}{2}(\cos 3\theta+\cos \theta)+i\frac{1}{2}(\cos\theta-\cos 3\theta)+\frac{1}{2}(\sin 3\theta+\sin\theta)d\theta \\ =\int \sin \theta +i\cos \theta d\theta=-\cos \theta +i\sin\theta +C\\
=-(\cos \theta-i\sin \theta)+C=-(\cos (-\theta)+i\sin (-\theta))+C=-\frac{1}{x}+C$$

You can find $\int x^a\:dx,a\in \mathbb Z$ in a similar manner.

Comment: Very nice and I have not even thought about using complex numbers. I like it

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^2} $$ Let $x=\sin(t)$ to make
$$I=\int \cot (t) \csc (t) \,dt=-\csc (t)$$

Comment: Why does the substitution $x = \sin t$ work if $x$ could be any non-zero real number, whereas $\sin t$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$?

Comment: Entire analytical functions that agree one an interval, agree everywhere

Comment: Doesn't computing the derivative of cosecant require the power rule?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, I didn't know this. You don't have a reference for this fact, by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=-1/x\;(x>0)$. Then
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\left(\frac1x-\frac1{x+h}\right)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1{x(x+h)}=\frac1{x^2}.$$Hence, for some constant $c$,
$$\int\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx= -\frac1x+c.$$

Comment: You lost me... how is this an answer to the OP? There was no issue about being able to compute the derivative of $\frac 1x$.

Comment: @PierreCarre OP was looking for the antiderivative, so he computed the derivative of the antiderivative, fair enough i guess lol

Answer (score 3):

I thought this answer might be useful to you as it involves simple manipulations.

$$\begin{align} \int \dfrac {1}{x^2}dx=\int \dfrac {1}{x} \times \dfrac {1}{x}dx=\int x^{-1}d(\ln x)=\int e^{\ln x^{-1}}d(\ln x)=\int e^{- \ln x}d(\ln x)=- \int e^{- \ln x}d(- \ln x)=-e^{- \ln x}+C=-\dfrac {1}{x}+C.\end{align}$$

Comment: Regardless I am not the asker or answerer, I do like this Answer and for some reason, I guess that I would do that in the same way as you did :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use $u=x^{-2}.\,v=x$ so $\int x^{-2}dx=x^{-1}+2\int x^{-2}dx\implies\int x^{-2}dx=-x^{-1}+C$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{1}{x^2} = e^{\ln \left ( \frac{1}{x^2} \right ) }  = e^{\ln \left ( x^{-2} \right ) } = e^{-2\ln (x  ) } = (e^{-2})^{\ln(x)} $$

$$ \text{when} ~~a \in \mathbb{R^+}: ~~~\int a^{\ln(x)} dx = \int \frac1x x^{\ln(a) + 1} dx \\ u=\ln x \Rightarrow du = \frac1x dx \\ = \int e^{(\ln(a) + 1)u} \\v = ( \ln(a) + 1)u \Rightarrow du = \frac{1}{( \ln(a) + 1)} dv \\ = \frac{1}{ \ln(a) + 1} \int e^v dv = \frac{1}{\ln(a) + 1} e^v+C= \frac{1}{\ln(a) + 1}e^{(\ln(a) + 1)u} + C = \frac{e^{(\ln(a) + 1)u}}{\ln(a) + 1} + C = \frac{x^{\ln( a ) + 1}}{\ln(a) + 1} + C $$

Substituting $a = e^{-2}$ we get:

$$ \frac{x^{-2 + 1}}{-2 + 1} + C = - \frac{1}{x} + C$$

Comment: It is very complicated dude

Comment: @coshsinh Complicated $\neq$ correct :-) especially when roughly all the answers are plain old $x = f(t)$  ;)

Comment: Given that simple ones are already taken........ And you never did mention that you want a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac 1{x^2} dx$$

Let
$v=x\implies dv=dx$

Let $u.v'=1\implies u=1 \implies u'=0$

$$I=\int\frac{uv'}{v^2}=\int\frac{u'}{v}-\frac{u}{v}=0-\frac{1}{x}=-\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx$$

Let $x=\cot(y)$, with $\frac{dx}{dy}=-\csc^2(y)$

$$I=-\int \frac{\csc^2(y)}{\cot^2(y)} \, dy=-\int \sec ^2(y) \, dy=-\tan(y)+C=-\frac{1}{x}+C$$

or

Let $x=\sec(y)$, with $\frac{dx}{dy}=\sec(y)\tan(y)$

$$I=\int \frac{\sec(y)\tan(y)}{\sec^2(y)} \, dy=\int \sin(y) \, dy=-\cos(y)+C=-\frac{1}{x}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

General way:

$$ x^n \cdot x^{-n} = 1$$

$$ nx^{n-1} x^{-n} + x^n \frac{d}{dx} x^{-n}=0$$

$$ \frac{n}{x^{n+1} } + \frac{d}{dx} x^{-n} = 0$$

Or,

$$ \frac{d}{dx}x^{-n} = \frac{-n}{x^{n+1} }$$

integrating both sides with $x$,

$$ x^{-n} +C = \int \frac{-n}{x^{n+1} } dx$$

Or,

$$ \frac{-n}{x^n} +C'  = \int \frac{1}{x^{n+1} } dx$$